# Subclass binding in wpf to datagrid column

Tags: binding, wpfdatagrid

I have a class of following details:

```
Public Class Contact
        Public prime As ContactPrime
End Class
Public Class ContactPrime
        Property Conid As String
        Property Conname As String
        Property Company As String
        Property Jobtitle As String
        Property Contactno As String
        Property Addr As String
        Property Type As String
End Class
```

I have a datagrid and the item source is set to contactlist(of Contact), the question is how can I display the Prime.Conname.

Additional Info:
Following is the current databinding in datagrid:

```
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="DataGrid1" Margin="0,10,0,0" Height="500" Width="695" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="True" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Conname}" Header="Name" Width="150" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Contactno}" Header="Numbers" Width="150"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Addr}" Header="Address" Width="150"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Type}" Header="Type" Width="80"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Company}" Header="Company" Width="70" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Jobtitle}" Header="Job" Width="70"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only bind to properties, not fields, so ensure that `Prime` is a property of `Contact`.

Also, if you wish the UI to be notified of changes, then you should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) on your types.

If you wish the UI to be notified of collection changes to the contact list, then this should implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx). The [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) type which is provided with WPF does this.

Comment: What if I declare property prime as contactprime instead of public prime as contactprime in Contact Class?  would it work then?

Comment: That is a requirement of binding - you can't bind against fields, only properties. Without seeing all of the code, it's difficult to say if this alone will fix your binding problems.

Comment: added more info into question.  Please let me know what more info is needed to be added.

Comment: You need to bind the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid to your collection of Contacts. Is there any reason you need Contact, and can't bind to a collection of ContactPrime directly? If you are binding to a collection (I would recommend ObservableCollection) of contacts, then you will need to change your binding expressions to e.g. {Binding Prime.Conname}

Comment: Yes, I binded to Itemsource to contacts and changed the binding property to prime.conname, the rows are being created but data is empty " ".  What could I have done wrong.

Comment: Have you changed your binding expression from {Binding Conname} to {Binding Prime.Conname} etc? Also, when you do populate the data. If it's after the view is initialised, then you will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your Contact and ContactPrime types.

Comment: But to my knowledge, I think It is not due to INotify property.  There must be some other configuration.

Comment: Your binding expressions are incorrect. You can check the debug window for binding errors. I'll ask again - have you changed your binding expressions from {Binding Conname} to {Binding Prime.Conname} etc?

Comment: No errors are issued and I have done the binding right as Prime.Conname

Comment: At what point do you populate your (presuambly ObservableCollection) of contacts?

Comment: I would guess what's happening is the collection change events are firing for the ObservableCollection (so you get a row for every item), but because your types don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged, the UI isn't being notified of those value changes. I would expect this only to be a problem if there are value changes after the view is initialised though.

Comment: I am not at need for any value changes yet, but as you said, the data is not being displayed even at the first time.

Comment: It depends at what point you are populating the data. It certainly would be worth implementing INPC anyway.